# Elaborate a mechanism to save objects in SQLite database without write any SQL commands

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

Actually, I'm writing all my SQL requests, and **it's a source of mistakes**. So I'm thinking about a way to save an object in my SQLite database **without write any SQL requests**. I think it's possible to set up a mechanism like that, but I don't know where I have to begin.
More, I want to use SQLite, and not Core Data.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want to store data in SQLite without any queries?

Comment: Would be hard. You can try https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb, but there are still manually written queries. Why not Core Data?

Comment: @doge I'm thinking about a solution to store data in SQLite with a proper and sure way, because it's easy to be mistaken writing SQL. But, this solution (if it exists...) can be with a few SQL commands. I just don't want to write a lot of SQL.

Comment: @MaciejOczko I'll try that. I don't want Core Data because all my app is in terms of SQLite, and I don't want to lost my times setting up it... :s

Comment: The proper way to store data in SQLite is to write queries i'm afraid. 
You could look at: http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/datamanipulation/ for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than Core Data, I don't know any solutions that completely free you from writing queries. There are quite a few ORMs out there that can help alleviate the pain, such as [Mojo Database](https://github.com/cpjolicoeur/mojo-database). A quick search on GitHub found 16 other ORM projects.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know the ORMs. I'll go in this direction.